# Need help with compressed string of unknown format

Tags: windows, decompress

I'm writing a parser for some xml scenario files.
Among other cleartext info there is a node 'Scenario_Compressed' which i like to analyse.
I've uploaded the content here:
http://www.lunex.net/temp/compstr.txt

can anybody of you help me identifing the type of compression?

thanks in advance
Lunex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @w4rex said, it definitely looks like base64. If you try to decode it like a regular base64 string, you end up with :

```
37 7a bc af 27 1c 00 03 d8 a0 33 34 30 78 00 00       7z..............
```

You recognize the '**7z**' magic of a 7zip file, and it's indeed a 30Ko archive containing a single file of 363Ko named 'default'. The file is password-protected though, so you could try to either brute-force it or reverse the application generating this file to find the password.

Comment: It's best to try to get the password from the binary instead of brute forcing it.

Comment: thank both you very much!
sadly I have absolutly no experience in disassembling and no idea how to extract the password from the binary, so i'm trying bruteforce now (thank you nvidia ;-)